# How to change size of modal dialog dynamically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dialog, size

I have a modal dialog in main page, then I add jPlayer to this dialog. All works fine, but I see only part of player in this dialog. How to change dialog size to the player size after the player is inserted?

i.e. I want to insert audio or video player to this dialog and they have different sizes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "media/track.mp3",
            }).jPlayer("play"); // auto play
        },
        ended: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "swf",
        supplied: "mp3"
    })
    .bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { // pause other instances of player when current one play
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    });
  });


 <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this)
                    .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true
                    })
                    .load(this.href);
            });

            $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using jQuery UI's dialog widget. If so then you can target the element via CSS (which will be better for performance than doing it in JavaScript):

```
.ui-dialog {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 150px;
}
```

If you have multiple dialogs then you should make the CSS selector above a bit more unique:

```
#root-element .ui-dialog {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 150px;
}
```

Also, this line should be throwing an error:

```
.attr("id", $(this)
```

And should be changed to something like this:

```
.attr("id", $(this).attr('id') + '_dialog')
```

Which will give the dialog an ID that is the same as the button clicked to create it with `_dialog` appended to the end.

**UPDATE**

If you do want to do this via JavaScript (say after a link is clicked) then you can use jQuery's `.css()` function to alter the element's dimensions as necessary:

```
$('#some-link').bind('click', function () {
    $('.ui-dialog').css({
        width  : 500px,
        height : 150px
    });
});
```

If you do not know the height/width values to use then you can check the values of the dialog content:

```
$('#some-link').bind('click', function () {
    var $dialog = $('.ui-dialog');
    $dialog.append('<div class="audio" style="width:123px; height: 321px;"></div>');
    $dialog.css({
        width  : $dialog.children('.audio').width(),//note that pixels will be assumed so it is not necessary to specify `px`
        height : $dialog.children('.audio').height()
    });
});
```

Comment: But it will be static values? I do not know them. For example: There is list of files(mp3, mp4) loading to the page and when user clicks file I need to open dialog and insert audio or video player. And in this point I need to change dialog size to fit player.

Comment: @Oleg I **updated** my answer, hopefully it will help more that the previous attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Load the data into your `$("<div></div>")` container before calling `dialog()`

Example:

```
var $dialogContent = $("<div></div>");

$dialogContent.load("some href", function () {
    // Initialize dialog in callback after the data has been loaded.
    $dialogContent.dialog(options);
});
```

Comment: i load only jPlayer to dialog.